# Dynamically created tables - grown together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I am almost there in creating several separate html-tables dynamically in jquery. But the problem for the moment is that the tables is grown together like siamese twins.
I have a divblock in the html-file called **PaymentTables** and to this div I add a created class-selector **paymentoptions**. All this is made in a function that, after its called, create a table - exactly what I want. But if I call this function two times, the classobjects seem to be grown togehter.

How can I solve this problem so they become separate?

**html**

```
<body>

    <div id="paymentTables">
    </div>

</body>
```

**javascript**

```
window.onload = function() {


   createTable();
   //createTable(); call this a second time generate a second table but that seem to be grown together with the first one.


};



function createTable(){

   var desc = "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur";
   var mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "paymentoptions_id" });
   var rows = 1;
   var cols = 2;
   for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
       var row = $('<tr></tr>').attr({ class: ["class1", "class2", "class3"].join(' ') }).appendTo(mytable);
       for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

          switch (j) {
            case 0: 
                $('<td valign="top"></td>').append('<input type="checkbox">').appendTo(row); 
            break;
            case 1:
                $('<td valign="top"></td>').html("text1<br><span>" + desc + "</span>").appendTo(row); 
            break;
           }
       }

   }

   $('#paymentTables').addClass("paymentoptions");

   mytable.appendTo(".paymentoptions");        
}
```

**css**

```
.paymentoptions {

   width: 300px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-radius: 5px;
}
```

called once

[image]

called a second time

[image]

Could an answer be that there is close-tag missing? But where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have two separate tables. The border makes them look like one table because you are placing the `paymentoptions` class on the surrounding `<div>`.

There is another issue with the HTML you are generating though. You are placing an `id` on the generated tables. All the generated tables will then have that same `id`, but `id` values should be unique.

Perhaps you should change this line:

```
var mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "paymentoptions_id" });
```

To this:

```
var mytable = $('<table></table>').addClass("paymentoptions");
```

And change this line:

```
mytable.appendTo(".paymentoptions");
```

To this:

```
mytable.appendTo("#paymentTables");
```

And remove this line:

```
$('#paymentTables').addClass("paymentoptions");
```

This makes it so only the surrounding container `<div>` has a unique `id`, while each of the tables has the same `paymentoptions` class.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9e7ccunt/)

Answer (score 1):

Your tables are not separate because you have applied the css for the div that contains all the tables.

So to fix that what you can do is instead of applying the css on parent div of all the tables apply it on individual tables.

In your css replace `.paymentoptions` with `table`.

See this for example.

```js
window.onload = function() {


   createTable();
  createTable();
  createTable();
   //createTable(); call this a second time generate a second table but that seem to be grown together with the first one.


};



function createTable(){

   var desc = "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur";
   var mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "paymentoptions_id" });
   var rows = 1;
   var cols = 2;
   for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
       var row = $('<tr></tr>').attr({ class: ["class1", "class2", "class3"].join(' ') }).appendTo(mytable);
       for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

          switch (j) {
            case 0: 
                $('<td valign="top"></td>').append('<input type="checkbox">').appendTo(row); 
            break;
            case 1:
                $('<td valign="top"></td>').html("text1<br><span>" + desc + "</span>").appendTo(row); 
            break;
        }
    }

}

   $('#paymentTables').addClass("paymentoptions");

   mytable.appendTo(".paymentoptions");        
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  table {

   width: 300px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-radius: 5px;
}
  </style>
<div id="paymentTables">
    </div>
```